# Change linux user default login directory

Tags: linux, vim

I have used the command `usermod -d /home/matt /home/matt/Documents/docs/`  to change my linux default login directory to `/home/matt/Documents/docs/`, but when i use vim to edit my code, my own configuration about vim didn't work, for example, my tab will equal to 8 spaces not 4 spaces(defined in my .vimrc). The configuration file is .vimrc and is under `/home/matt/.vimrc`.

The following is the content of my .vimrc:

```
set hlsearch
set backspace=2
set autoindent
set ruler
set nu
set bg=dark
syntax on
set shiftwidth=4
set softtabstop=4
```

if i copy my .vimrc from `/home/matt/` to my new home directory(`/home/matt/Documents/docs/`), things work well. But when i change my home and i have to copy my .vimrc at the same time, it terrible. Anyone has a better solution?

Comment: If switching home directories is only to save one `cd Documents/docs`, you'd be better off writing this `cd` in your `/home/matt/.bashrc`.

Answer (score 3):

The usermod command changes your home directory, where *.vimrc* is expected to be.

I suggest you to put the file in one directory, and then create a link (through **ln -s**) from the other directory.

Comment: but if change my home directory next time, i will still need to create a link. It's still awkward. :(

Comment: Why do you switch homes so rapidly? I'd say you have to move many more settings, too (unless Vim is the only tool you're using).

Comment: @Barnett_Love well, what did you expect Vim to do? Switching home directories is something which is usually done only once.

Comment: You should understand why you need to change your home directory so often. It's quite unusual to change your own home directory...

Comment: @Claudio Well, in fact i do some coding exercises under **/home/matt/Documents/docs** , so every time i login, i have to type command **cd /home/matt/Documets/docs**. I just want to type less word. So i use command ***usermod***

Comment: There are better ways to make it easier to get to that directory -- you shouldn't be changing your home directory to do something like that. If you put `alias foo="cd/home/matt/Documents/docs"` in your `.bashrc`, (assuming you're using bash -- if you don't know if you are, or don't know what that means, ask) you can then use `foo` to get to that directory. Of course, you can change `foo` to be something else.

Comment: @pandubear Ah, thanks. It works. I think it's what that i want to do at the beginning.

Comment: Typical example of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please give more background next time, and state your final goal? When a question is only about a small technical step, it's difficult to provide a good answer.