# Command to change the default home directory of a user

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I would like to know whether there is any simple shell command to change the user home directory in Linux/Unix (one similar to **chsh** which changes the default login shell of an existing valid user) without touching the `/etc/passwd` file. Thanks

Comment: Why don't you want to touch the `/etc/passwd` file? You'll need to!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20071714/change-linux-user-default-login-directory, says that
`usermod -d /home/userxx /home/useryy` to change linux default login directory to /home/useryy

Comment: Why do you ask about the *default* home directory? Do you want to change the home directory of one particular existing user, or of all users added in the future? Notice that `chsh` don't change the *default* login shell, but just the login shell of a given user... To change the `HOME` of a particular user, just edit `/etc/passwd`

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has nothing to do with programming and would have been best suited for [unix.se] **or** [su].

Answer (score 485):

Ibrahim's comment on the other answer is the correct way to alter an existing user's home directory.

#### Change the user's home directory:

```
usermod -d /newhome/username username
```

`usermod` is the command to edit an existing user. 
`-d` (abbreviation for `--home`) will change the user's home directory.

#### Change the user's home directory + Move the contents of the user's current directory:

```
usermod -m -d /newhome/username username
```

`-m` (abbreviation for `--move-home`) will move the content from the user's current directory to the new directory.

Comment: Not only move the content, I see it more like move whole folder = original folder (`/home/username` typically) is removed.

Comment: @STW Is this a reversible task? Meaning if I just run it once and then flip the parameters, will my home directory be exactly the way it was before?

Comment: @DanGordon whatever you put in the `/newhome/username` argument will be the user's home directory.  You can set it back to their previous home directory if you know what it was, but there's no "undo" option.

Comment: The order of options for the second command is wrong. `usermod -m -d /newhome/username username` works.

Comment: @Dominik thanks -- there's a chance it's different based on OS (Mac vs Linux vs BSD, etc), of course it could also just be incorrect

Comment: `usermod: user himanshu is currently used by process 140`

Comment: This is quite useless- you can't change stuff while logged into the user.

Comment: @MDev How is it useless. Just login as another user or root...

Comment: @KolonUK because that's the only correct way really. When you are logged in as the user, you have applications opened which rely on that home directory. You shouldn't be changing the location while everything is running. So yeah, creating a new user account and deleting is not that bad at all. Or you could set a password for root and login as root in a new TTY.

Answer (score 33):

From [Linux Change Default User Home Directory While Adding A New User](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-change-default-home-directory/):

> Simply open this file using a text editor, type:
>
> ```
> vi /etc/default/useradd
> ```
>
> The default home directory defined by HOME variable, find line that
>   read as follows:
>
> ```
> HOME=/home
> ```
>
> Replace with:
>
> ```
> HOME=/iscsi/user
> ```
>
> Save and close the file. Now you can add user using regular useradd
>   command:
>
> ```
> # useradd vivek
> # passwd vivek
> ```
>
> Verify user information:
>
> ```
> # finger vivek
> ```

Comment: `usermod -m -d /path/to/new/login/home/dir  user`  changes existing user home directory to a new login directory which is created if it does not already exist, option -m moves the contents of the current home directory to the new home dir

Answer (score 27):

The accepted answer is faulty, since the contents from the initial user folder are not moved using it.  I am going to add another answer to correct it:

```
sudo usermod -d /newhome/username -m username
```

You don't need to create the folder with username and this will also move your files from the initial user folder to /newhome/username folder.

Answer (score 6):

In case other readers look for information on the `adduser` command.

Edit `/etc/adduser.conf`

Set `DHOME` variable

Answer (score 5):

You can do it with:

```
/etc/passwd
```

Edit the user home directory and then move the required files and directories to it:

```
cp/mv -r /home/$user/.bash* /home/newdir

.bash_profile
.ssh/
```

Set the correct permission

```
chmod -R $user:$user /home/newdir/.bash*
```

Answer (score 2):

Found out that this breaks some applications, the better way to do it is

In addition to symlink, on more recent distros and filesystems, as root you can also use bind-mount:

```bash
mkdir /home/username 
mount --bind --verbose /extra-home/username /home/username
```

This is useful for allowing access "through" the /home directory to subdirs via daemons that are otherwise configured to avoid pathing through symlinks (apache, ftpd, etc.).

You have to remember (or init script) to bind upon restarts, of course.

An example init script in `/etc/fstab` is

```bash
/extra-home/username /home/username none defaults,bind 0 0
```

Answer (score -4):

usermod -m -d /newhome username

Comment: Please explain your answer in more detail.