# Setting vagrant home directory during provisioning

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I have a VM that I'm pulling down with vagrant and using a VERY basic vagrant file

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  # The most common configuration options are documented and commented below.
  # For a complete reference, please see the online documentation at
  # https://docs.vagrantup.com.

  # Every Vagrant development environment requires a box. You can search for
  # boxes at https://atlas.hashicorp.com/search.
  config.vm.box = "vagrant-rhel-devel"

  config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.33.101"
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant"

  config.ssh.username = "vagrant"
  config.ssh.password = "vagrant"

 config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    # Display the VirtualBox GUI when booting the machine
    # vb.gui = true

    # Enable 3d Rendering
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--accelerate3d", "on"]

    # Sets 32megs video ram, higher number here = more POWERS
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--vram", "32"]

  #   # Customize the amount of memory on the VM:
  #   vb.memory = "1024"

    vb.name = "RedHat 3D"

  end
end
```

My issue is that the vagrant user gets a home directory of `/localhome/vagrant` and I'd like him to have `/home/vagrant` as the home directory.

Is this something I'm able to change with provisioning or is it something that is set in the VM itself?  I'm rather unskilled at the provisioning step at the moment so an example would be great.

Comment: where did you download the box ? it sounds weird to have localhome as home directory

Answer (score 0):

The `HOME` directory has been set when the user has been created so this was done before the VM was packaged as vagrant box.

[From there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26427748/4296747), you should be able to change that with

```
usermod -m -d /path/to/new/home/dir userNameHere
```

so in your case it would be

```
usermod -m -d /home/vagrant vagrant
```

check if you have existing files under the /localhome directory that would need to be copied into the new one (bash preferences file)

if you do not plan to destroy/create a bunch of new VM from this box, its not needed to add as provisioning; if you do plan to use this box and create lot of new VM, then it could make sense, you would just need to add an `inline shell` provision