# ${user.home} in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Disk

Tags: linux, spring, ubuntu, spring-boot, ubuntu-14.04

I have a basic SpringBoot app. using Spring Initializer, embedded Tomcat, Thymeleaf template engine, and package as an executable JAR file.

This is one of my config class

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableCaching
@PropertySource("file:///${user.home}/.devices/application-common.properties")
public class DeviceApplicationConfig {
..
}
```

I enter in the linode machine with `devuser`:

```
devuser@localhost:~$ pwd
/home/devuser
```

then I run the SpringBoot app. from the folder `/var/devices`, But I have this error, while I was expecting the program search the file in: `/home/devuser/.devices/application-common.properties`

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /root/.devices/application-common.properties (No such file or directory)
```

and checking the processes it seems than the application is run by devuser:

```
devuser  12922  1.3 12.3 2478348 252840 ?      Sl   15:16   0:37 java -jar devices-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Comment: Looks like you need to run the application the user devuser as opposed to root?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to configure `user.home` directory and run application from this user. for configuration of `user.home` you can refer bellow `stackoverflow` link :

[Command to change the default home directory of a user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20797819/command-to-change-the-default-home-directory-of-a-user)