# Changing directory from home to root in camel-ftp

Tags: apache-camel, dsl, camel-ftp

I am using the following in my Apache Camel configuration:

```
<camel:route errorHandlerRef="loggingErrorHandler" id="ROUTE_ICL">

    <camel:from uri="file:{{camel.route.icl.from.file.path}}?filter=#fileFilterMAVRO&amp;initialDelay={{camel.route.from.file.initialDelay}}&amp;delay={{camel.route.from.file.delay}}&amp;useFixedDelay=true&amp;runLoggingLevel=TRACE&amp;startingDirectoryMustExist={{camel.route.from.file.startingDirectoryMustExist}}&amp;autoCreate={{camel.route.from.file.autoCreate}}&amp;maxMessagesPerPoll={{camel.route.from.file.maxMessagesPerPoll}}&amp;eagerMaxMessagesPerPoll=true&amp;delete=false&amp;readLock=idempotent&amp;readLockLoggingLevel=OFF&amp;readLockRemoveOnRollback=false&amp;readLockRemoveOnCommit=false&amp;idempotent=true&amp;idempotentKey=${file:onlyname}&amp;idempotentRepository=#iclMessageIdRepository&amp;recursive=false&amp;move={{camel.route.icl.complete.file.path}}&amp;moveFailed={{camel.route.icl.failed.file.path}}" />

    <camel:to uri="sftp://user1@ecomt199.qintra.com:22/nas/tst2/inputfiles?password=Pass1234&amp;runLoggingLevel=TRACE"/>

</camel:route>
```

Now, this is working. It is able to sftp my file.

Problem is I want my file to be at: /nas/tst2/inputfiles. But it is going at: /home/user1/nas/tst2/inputfiles

Now, how can I make it for going it at */nas/tst2/inputfiles*? /nas/ and /home/ both are on <root>/.

The problem is changing this default */home/*.

Which attribute can I use? I am not able to find or understand how to do it in Camel DSL.

Comment: Thanks to @mcode, this is resolved by adding "/../.." and using stepwise=true.

Comment: As of camel v2.6, `stepwise=true` is the default behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Camel indeed doesn't allow fully qualified paths in the current version. However, as long as the user has the privileges, you could use a path like this as a workaround:

```
../../../../../../../../this_is_the_root_folder/usr/....
```

You basically start with the user's directory and then go up in the tree until you reach root. You only need to make sure that you added enough `../../` to get to the root.

It is not the nicest solution, but it is simple and worked for me.

Comment: I understand your logic. But it's not working for me.

Comment: Thanks man !
It's resolved, I had to add stepwise=true.
Thank you very much :)

Comment: You could do us the favor and mark the answer then as correct ;-)

Comment: stackoverflow is not allowing me to do any action, not even a UP arrow click due to less reputation score.
i added about yu in my comment.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the best solution is in the Camel DSL. The user you use for SFTP has its root in the home directory.

I think a good solution is to configure another user in the FTP server with the correct root directory, where you want to put your files.

Comment: That will only change the username in /home/ dir, like /home/user2/. I was looking if I could get any other idea for how to do get to the main "/" <root> dir in xml dsl.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20797819/command-to-change-the-default-home-directory-of-a-user

Comment: In camel, where are we going to do this? It says for Linux.

Comment: You use this in you target system to repoint the home dir for the user, then it's very easy to use sftp. With better security use chroot command.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  The current camel-ftp implementation specifically does not allow fully qualified paths.  All paths are relative to the user's home directory.

To get around this for my project I forked the component and removed the code that strips the leading path separator character.

Comment: Can you help me with elaborate info for how to do that?

Comment: get the camel-ftp component from GitHub.  Then comment out the use of the method org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.FtpUtils. ensureRelativeFtpDirectory.