# How to change the default directory for Linux at startup

Tags: bash

I'm using Linux doing some course labs,it always startup with the default path, rather than my working directory, very inconvenient.
this is the default:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zi60.png)

and I want it to be like this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBshl.png)

what should I do?

=======update=============

Solution is in this [Start all sessions in a directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/140602/how-do-i-start-all-shell-sessions-in-a-directory-other-than-home/140603#140603?newreg=03ee688d7f324dc189098581cf89e29b)

Comment: Try this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20797819/command-to-change-the-default-home-directory-of-a-user

Comment: Type `vim ~/.bashrc` then press `Shift G` to move to the last line. Press `a` to append to the last line and press `[Enter]` to create a new line. Then enter `"cd /mnt/c/Users/litang/githubWorkSpace/MIT-6.824/src/main"`, press `[Esc]` to return to command-mode. Type `:wq` to save and quit. That will add the command to change to your working directory. Alternatively, you can add an alias ,e .g. `alias wd='cd /mnt/c/Users/litang/githubWorkSpace/MIT-6.824/src/main'` as the last line. Then after you boot, just enter `wd` to go to your working directory.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Please don't put answers (especially extremely detailed answers) in a comment.

Comment: Yes, referring to another duplicate or similar would be easier and better. Hardly seems like something that needs a full answer, and it is right on the edge of off-topic

Answer (score 1):

Just run the following command in your terminal:

```
echo "cd ~/Desktop/Java\ Files" >> ~/.bashrc
```

The above command will add a new line in your `~/.bashrc` file that contain `cd ~/Desktop/Java\ Files` and that will change your default working directory to `/home/Varun/Desktop/Java Files` when you will open the terminal.

if you are still in doubt, you can read here
https://askubuntu.com/questions/332062/setting-default-path-when-opening-a-terminal-session

Comment: What does `~/Desktop/Java\ Files` have to do with this question??

Comment: @Liyando : Editing a text file using commands is somewhat odd. Text editors have been invented already!

Answer (score 0):

I think your question has to do with the concept of HOME directory.
To change a user's home dir use this command:

```
usermod -m -d /newhome/username username
```

Explanation:

**usermod**    command to change user attributes
**-d**    (abbreviation for --home) will change the user's home directory
**-m**    (abbreviation for --move-home) will move the content from the user's current directory to the new directory

You can omit the **-m** option if you don't need to move files from the old home to the new.